# Disabling a UIButton in a UITableViewCell with cell reusability

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UIButton` in each of my `UITableViewCell`s. When the button is pressed I am disabling it so that the user cannot press it again (it is a like button). However, when the user scrolls passed a cell and the scrolls back to the cell the button is selectable once again. I'm guessing this is because the cell is redrawn when the user comes back to it, resetting the button. Is there a way I can avoid this? My code is below

**Code**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifer = @"cellName";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifer];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifer];
    }
    UIButton *ilikeit = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [ilikeit addTarget:self action:@selector(like:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    ilikeit.frame = CGRectMake(55, h+70, 45, 25);
    [cell addSubview:ilikeit];
    return cell;
}

-(void) like:(id) sender {
    ((UIButton *)sender).enabled = NO;
}
```

Comment: You need to keep *state* in your tableview datasource model object.

Comment: add me to skype (amir.ios) to accept the code. I have fixed your issue

Answer (score 1):

You can store the button state in your data model for the tableview class.

Say the TableView is loading data from a class MyData which looks like this:

```
@interface MyData: NSObject

    // Your other data here such as strings etc
    NSString *otherData;
    // Here add a selected flag
    BOOL selected;

@end
```

in the TableViewDelegate, read and write to this model.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    MyData *thisCellData = [yourGlobalMyDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // set other data
    if (thisCellData.selected){
           // Hide the button
           // Do other stuff as needed for this button
    }
    else {
            // Show the button
           // Do other stuff as needed for this button

    }
}
```

The same data model should be updated when user selects the button.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`Problem- 1`  You are creating your button every time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called.
`Problem- 2`  You have no code to keep the state of your button with cell reusability, that's why it is refreshed when cell is going for reuse.

`Solution-` For this you have to keep your selected button state. Make a global `NSInteger` variable. And set its value as `sender.tag` value in `like:` method. And use -

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if (cell == nil)
  {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifer];

     // here create your UIButton
     // Set its tag to indexPath.row
     // add this to cell as subview
  }

  // find button of current cell using tag 
  UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
  // place your check here if button tag matches with selected tag then disable btn here.
  // Else use setEnable with YES parameter. 
}
```